# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') Next 13 Using getStaticProps

Tags: reactjs, github, next.js, fetch-api, github-api

I was trying to fetch my data from github using getStaticProps for more performance and it returns this error even when I do a "console.log" it returns me the array but I can't map it so what am I missing

code:

```
"use client";

import { GetStaticProps } from "next";

interface PostGithubProps {
  posts: {
    name: string
  }[]
}

export default function Github({ posts }: PostGithubProps) {
  return(
    <>
     {posts.map(post => {
       <p key={post.name}>{post.name}</p>
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/{myuser}/repos')
  const posts = await res.json()

  return { 
    props: {
      posts
    }
  }
}
```

So what am I missing to do this map works, as I already said on console return the array of repos from github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this new version of Next we don't need getStaticProps anymore my mistake .
I solve it like this:

```
interface PostGithubProps {
  name: string
}

export default async function Github() {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/{myuser}/repos`, {
    next: {
      revalidate: 60 * 60 * 24, // 24 hours
    },
  })

  const repositories = await response.json()

  return (
      {repositories.map((repos: PostGithubProps) => (
        <p key={repos.name}>
          {repos.name}
        </p>
       ))}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, on the initial render, your posts are not available so you must check for undefined value first something like this :

```
import { GetStaticProps } from "next";

interface PostGithubProps {
  posts: {
    name: string
  }[]
}

export default function Github({ posts }: PostGithubProps) {
  if(!posts) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  return(
    <>
     {posts.map(post => {
       <p key={post.name}>{post.name}</p>
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/{myuser}/repos')
  const posts = await res.json()

  return { 
    props: {
      posts
    }
  }
}
```